How can I write a regex to not match groups of letters?
How could I write a regex RE2 to match everything that not starts with 'BXR' or 'RTX' or 'KYC'?
What I tried is ^[^BXR|RTX|KYC] , is there a way to do it?

You seem to be confusing [] with ().

There's an open feature request for negative lookahead in RE2: https://github.com/google/re2/issues/156

You would probably need to exclude and list each allowed option ending up with a long regex, e.g. ^(?:..?$|[^BRK]..|.[^XTY].|..[^RXC]|BX[^R]|B[TY]|RT[^X]|R[XY]|KY[^C]|K[TX]).* (the \n in demo is just for multiline showcase)
